# Microsoft Power BI | TOP 5 client's sales and sales % of total ( not just the top 5 )

Tags: powerbi

I need to get Total Sales and Sales % of total ( not just the top 5 ) for my top 5 clients.

I tried the % total feature in the values but after filtering the top 5 clients, the % total is calculated as 100% of the top 5 clients instead of the total clients in the date slicer.

How do I achieve the sales and Sales % of the total in the TOP N clients?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an alternative solution would be to create a measure/column that calculates a percentage sales overall and slot that in instead.

something along the Lines of client[sales] / all(client[sales], (ignoring all filters).

Answer (score 0):

Creating the measure worked for me

GP% of top 5 Customer =

> DIVIDE (
>
> SUM ( Transaction[GrossProfit] ),
>
> CALCULATE ( SUM (  Transaction[GrossProfit] , ALL
>   (Customer[CustomerName])
>
> ))